# switch statement with and without brace

Tags: c, assembly, scope, switch-statement

I just write a simple program to learn c programming

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int main()
  4 {
  5         int a = 5;
  6         switch(a)
  7         {
  8                 case 0:
  9                         {
 10                         ;
 11                         int a = 10;
 12                         printf("%d\n",a);
 13                         break;
 14                         }
 15                 default :
 16                         printf("%d",a);
 17 
 18         }
 19         return 0;
 20 }
```

---

*Output:* **5**
When I forgot the brace it turns to be:

```
  8                 case 0:
  9                        
 10                         ;
 11                         int a = 10;
 12                         printf("%d\n",a);
 13                         break;
 14
```

---

*Output:* **0**

I'm little confused about this and try to compile and debug:

---

```
-   1    0x000000000040051c <+0>:     push   %rbp                          |-   1    0x000000000040051c <+0>:     push   %rbp
|   2    0x000000000040051d <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp                     ||   2    0x000000000040051d <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
|   3    0x0000000000400520 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp                    ||   3    0x0000000000400520 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
|   4 => 0x0000000000400524 <+8>:     movl   $0x5,-0x8(%rbp)               ||   4 => 0x0000000000400524 <+8>:     movl   $0x5,-0x8(%rbp)
|   5    0x000000000040052b <+15>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax               ||   5    0x000000000040052b <+15>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
|   6    0x000000000040052e <+18>:    test   %eax,%eax                     ||   6    0x000000000040052e <+18>:    test   %eax,%eax
|   7    0x0000000000400530 <+20>:    jne    0x40054f <main+51>            ||   7    0x0000000000400530 <+20>:    jne    0x40054f <main+51>
|   8    0x0000000000400532 <+22>:    movl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)               ||   8    0x0000000000400532 <+22>:    movl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)
    9    0x0000000000400539 <+29>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax               |    9    0x0000000000400539 <+29>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   10    0x000000000040053c <+32>:    mov    %eax,%esi                     |   10    0x000000000040053c <+32>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   11    0x000000000040053e <+34>:    mov    $0x400614,%edi                |   11    0x000000000040053e <+34>:    mov    $0x400614,%edi
   12    0x0000000000400543 <+39>:    mov    $0x0,%eax                     |   12    0x0000000000400543 <+39>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   13    0x0000000000400548 <+44>:    callq  0x4003f0 <printf@plt>         |   13    0x0000000000400548 <+44>:    callq  0x4003f0 <printf@plt>
   14    0x000000000040054d <+49>:    jmp    0x400563 <main+71>            |   14    0x000000000040054d <+49>:    jmp    0x400563 <main+71>
   15    0x000000000040054f <+51>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax               |   15    0x000000000040054f <+51>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax              
   16    0x0000000000400552 <+54>:    mov    %eax,%esi                     |   16    0x0000000000400552 <+54>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   17    0x0000000000400554 <+56>:    mov    $0x400618,%edi                |   17    0x0000000000400554 <+56>:    mov    $0x400618,%edi
   18    0x0000000000400559 <+61>:    mov    $0x0,%eax                     |   18    0x0000000000400559 <+61>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   19    0x000000000040055e <+66>:    callq  0x4003f0 <printf@plt>         |   19    0x000000000040055e <+66>:    callq  0x4003f0 <printf@plt>
   20    0x0000000000400563 <+71>:    mov    $0x0,%eax                     |   20    0x0000000000400563 <+71>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   21    0x0000000000400568 <+76>:    leaveq                               |   21    0x0000000000400568 <+76>:    leaveq 
+  22 +--  2 lines: 0x0000000000400569 <+77>: retq   ----------------------|+  22 +--  2 lines: 0x0000000000400569 <+77>: retq   ---------------------
```

A little diffrent but vital:

```
$ diff with.txt without.txt 
15c15
<    0x000000000040054f <+51>:  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
---
>    0x000000000040054f <+51>:  mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I learn a lesson that `gcc -Wall` is always a good practice.

Comment: The version without the braces doesn't compile. It's not valid C. And the first version doesn't have the output that you claim. I've no idea why you bother with assembly here. Get rid of it and show us the real code. You need to slow down and get a grip on what you are doing. If you can't even manage to post the code that you are running, how can you hope to understand the program. Also, your `main` is wrong. You mean `int main(void)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan gcc is compile this code without complaining unless you set -Wall which is gives you "warning: 'a' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]".

Comment: @sergey Not the second version with no braces. At least not for me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan we are talking about gcc, not g++

Comment: @DavidHeffernan here the log "C:\WORK\nuwen\MinGW>gcc -Wall -std=c99 a.c
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:14:19: warning: 'a' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

C:\WORK\nuwen\MinGW>g++ a.c
a.c: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
a.c:13:13: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
a.c:10:17: error:   crosses initialization of 'int a'

C:\WORK\nuwen\MinGW>"

Comment: @Sergey Who mentioned g++? The question is tagged C.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry,I write `5` to `10` sorry for that.

Comment: So, yes, the compiler does warn for a not initialized with -Wall. I mentioned that g++ gives an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have to really work at getting to this point, as it won't compile without the extra semicolon in your code. Which makes me think this is contrived example made up for an interview or some such.

In your second example, the variable a (inner) is created at the switch braces { }, but it is not initialized at that level, since the initialization is only in the case 0: code. So the value of a is completely random (happens to be zero)

Either way, bad coding style! Don't forget to use braces in case-statements if you introduce variables. [In g++ you actually get an error "jump to case-label crosses initialization of 'int a']

So, first of all, `gcc -Wall` will give a warning for "uninitalized variable".

If we consider this example:

```
int a = 111;

int main()
{
    int a = 2;

    printf("a=%d\n", a);
}
```

I don't think anyone would argue the case of "which a do we mean", right?

Or if we have:

```
 int main()
 {
    int x = 12;

    int a = 11;
    if(x == 12)
    {
         int a = 2;

         printf("a=%d\n", a);
    }

  }
```

Again, it's pretty obvious what's going on here, right?

If we rewrite your code to show what actually happens:

```
int main()
{
        int a = 5;
        switch(a)
        { 
           int a;
               case 0:
                a=10 ;
                        printf("%d\n",a);
                        break;
                default :
                        printf("%d",a);

        }
        return 0;
}
```

Now, that's semantically the same thing as your code in the second variant. It just looks a bit different!

Comment: why it doesn't shadow the value of `a` in the outer but `a` in the `case 0`

Comment: Because the variable location is defined by the placement of the {} that surrounds it. I'll amend my answer a little bit...

Comment: Why does compile do such an action ?any clue in stadard?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the language specification. Unfortunately, I can't quote exact section and paragraph, but the above explains HOW it works and why you get the result you get (naturally, if I change `int a` to `int a = 42;`, you wouldn't be surprised to see 42 being shown, right?

Answer (score 1):

Without '{}', you just jump over the initialization of the inner variable 'a' (it still defined, though), so you get an uninitialized 'a', in this case, it is '0'.

BTW, with '{}', it should output '5'.

Comment: I have defined a in `line 5` `int a = 5;`?

Comment: Nope, without '{}', the inner 'a' shadows the outer 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the usage of assembly here in the post as 
it helps to understand the code in a better way.

Now what happened here.

Lets discuss this issue in cases

case 1 :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=5;

    switch(a)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            ;
            int a = 10;
            printf("%d in case 0\n",a);
            break;
            ;
        }
        default:
            printf("%d in default case\n",a);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Case 1 Assembly:

```
    .file   "test1.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d in case 0\n"
.LC1:
    .string "%d in default case\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $5, 28(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L6
.L3:
    movl    $10, 24(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    24(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    jmp .L4
.L6:
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    movl    28(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
.L4:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

case 1 o/p: 
root@local-host#./a.out
5 in default case

Explanation :
This is as expected because as you can see the statement in assembly

```
movl    $5, 28(%esp)
```

we are copying / moving 5 to 28(%esp) location

```
movl    28(%esp), %eax
testl   %eax, %eax its a switch equivalent
```

in main tag

here 28(%esp) is nothing but the value of a (int a=5;)

And at L3 all 24(%esp) is used to store the value 10
Please note that ebx register is used hereas new a.
And L6 is the default case now look at the following statement
movl    28(%esp), %edx
here 28(%esp) (which is nothing but value of a) is copied to o/p hence our o/p is as expected.

Case 2:

## include

int main()
    {
    int a=5;

```
switch(a)
    {
    case 0:
        ;
        int a = 10;
        printf("%d in case 0\n",a);
        break;
    default:
        printf("%d in default case\n",a);
        break;
    }
```

return 0;
    }

Case 2 Assembly:
    .file   "test1.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d in case 0\n"
.LC1:
    .string "%d in default case\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $5, 28(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L6
.L3:
    movl    $10, 24(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    24(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    jmp .L4
.L6:
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    movl    24(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
.L4:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret

Case 2 o/p:
root@local-host#./a.out
134513723 in default case

A garbage value 
Let me explain here also the 28(%esp) is the value of a
Now take a close look at L3 and L6 labels
Here is what you find during the code at 24%esp again a is created only if the case 0 satisfies.
As the case of 0 is not satisfied the 24%esp will not get initialised i.e int a = 10;

And we are going to default which is L6 and we are trying to get 24%esp value which is not yet 
initilised (but it is a valid location) as we havent went to case 0.
Thats why we are getting garbage value.

Case 3:

## include

int main()
    {
    int a=5;

```
switch(a)
    {
    case 5:
        ;
        int a = 10;
        printf("%d in case 5\n",a);
    default:
        printf("%d in default case\n",a);
        break;
    }
```

return 0;
    }

Case 3 assembly:
    .file   "test1.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d in case 5\n"
.LC1:
    .string "%d in default case\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $5, 28(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    cmpl    $5, %eax
    jne .L2
.L3:
    movl    $10, 24(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    24(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
.L2:
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    movl    24(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret

Case 3 o/p:
root@local-host#./a.out
10 in case 0
10 in default case

Here as you can see that the new a is created at 24(%esp) and initailised at case 5 so the value will be same 
at default location.

In L3 label
movl    24(%esp), %edx 
In L2 Label
movl    24(%esp), %edx

So same location 24(%esp) is used which is created and initialised at cse 5 and flow through the default.

Case 4:

## include

int main()
    {
    int a=5;

```
switch(a)
    {
    case 0:
        ;
        static int a = 10;
        printf("%d in case 0\n",a);
        break;
    default:
        printf("%d in default\n",a);
        break;
    }
```

return 0;
    }

Case 4 Assembley:
    .file   "test1.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d in case 0\n"
.LC1:
    .string "%d in default\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $5, 28(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L6
.L3:
    movl    a.1706, %edx
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    jmp .L4
.L6:
    movl    a.1706, %edx
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
.L4:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   a.1706, @object
    .size   a.1706, 4
a.1706:
    .long   10
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits

Case 4 O/p:
root@local-host#./a.out
10 in default

This makes sense as the static type is a global and stored in the data section so
During execution the global value i.e the static int a is in data section and initialized as 10.

Case 5:

## include

int main()
    {
    int a=5;

```
switch(a)
    {
    case 0:
        {
        ;
        static int a = 10;
        printf("%d in case 0\n",a);
        break;
        }
    default:
        printf("%d in default\n",a);
        break;
    }
```

return 0;
    }

Case 5 Assembly:
    .file   "test1.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d in case 0\n"
.LC1:
    .string "%d in default\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $5, 28(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L6
.L3:
    movl    a.1706, %edx
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    jmp .L4
.L6:
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    movl    28(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
.L4:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   a.1706, @object
    .size   a.1706, 4
a.1706:
    .long   10
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits

Case 5 O/p:
root@local-host#./a.out
5 in default

Here due to the '{' delimiters the static value is confined to case 0 at assembler stage
the default case is still getting the  value from 28(%esp) which is as expected as at assemble time case 0 has static and is out of scope for default.

You can try different formats by removing breaks and applying '{' '}' delimiters

Never forget to look it in terms of scope and wrto assembly code.

Comment: The formatting of this answer had gone very badly wrong.  I've tidied it up for case 1; you could use this as a template to fix up the remaining cases if you wanted.